# Validation Hint on Controls in Asp.Net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I want implement Validation Hint on my Form Fields Same as Hotmail.com See the Below Screenshot. Can Any Tell me What should i do for that ? Jquery, Javascript or CSS Please Post Some tutorial that will be Great.

[image]

regards,

Comment: Here's one I like that is very usable/style-able: http://flowplayer.org/tools/validator/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has a great plugin:

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

That plugin is highly regarded and offers all the customization you need.

As far as styling goes the validation Hotmail uses is just a tooltip or div that is styled to look like a tooltip.

Some tooltip plugins:

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/

Answer (score 0):

Qtip is a good tooltip plugin and can customised to great extent.
http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/